# The crash I got on Android version 4 phones

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

In Firebase Crashlytics, I get the following error on Android version 4 phones.
The file ic_arrow_back_black_24dp.xml exists in drawable folders. Please help.
Thanks

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.defaultmailproject.myproject/com.defaultmailproject.myproject.ui.activities.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800c9
```

MainActivity Toolbar ic_arrow_back_black_24.dp.xml;

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);
    upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your error just you need to move your file [ic_arrow_back_black_24dp] from [drawable-hdpi-v4] folder to any other folder.

you need to move your XML file Drawable folder [drawable-hdpi-v4] to[drawable-hdpi] or any other folder like [drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi,drawable-xxxhdpi]
Once you move you XML file from above any one folder your problem solved.

**Don't put your file inside any drawable-v4 folder**

Comment: Hi, The drawable-hdpi-v4 folder is not in my RES folder.
There are folders named drawable-hdpi.

Comment: You can move your XML file inside your drawable folder

Answer (score 0):

You can check below couple of possible solutions:

1. Make sure that `R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp.xml` exists in
   both **drawable** and `drawable-24` directories.
2. Go under **/res** folder of your project, create a new directory,
   name it `drawable-v19`, and copy
   `R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp.xml` into it.

Hint: v-19 is for **Android 4**